# How can i get IP of my glass when it is connected by bluetooth to my mobile?

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk, google-mirror-api

I have my glass paired by bluetooth with my mobile. My mobile is connected to a WiFi network (and my glass isn't connected to WiFi, it uses the WiFi of my mobile).

I know I can get IP local ip addres with this code:

```
        WifiManager wifiMgr = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiMgr.getConnectionInfo();
    int ip = wifiInfo.getIpAddress();
    String ipAddress = Formatter.formatIpAddress(ip);
```

It's work OK if i run this code in a tablet o smartphone, but if i run it in my glass i get ip 0.0.0.0 ( remeber that my glass is connected by bluetooth to my mobile and this one is which has network connection).

So, any suggestions? I need this because i have a Socket in my glass and i need the IP.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The code can now be called by any activity

```
public String getIP(){
    WifiManager wifiMgr = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiMgr.getConnectionInfo();
    int ip = wifiInfo.getIpAddress();
    String ipAddress = Formatter.formatIpAddress(ip);
}
```

To anyone who is interested. The above code DID work for me in an Activity. Try:

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this,
              "IP Address:\n\r"+getIP(this), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.show();
```

Perhaps your UI isn't updating, or print it to the log. Another possibility is that you need to add the following to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

Not sure if you need both, but I need both for my application as I do a lot of networking which it sounds like you are too.