# Google Glass as external monitor

Tags: google-glass

Is there any way to mirror a computer screen onto Google Glass? There is a lot of information for glass->computer, but I cannot find any for computer-> glass. Any help will be appreciated.

So far this http://www.howtousegoogleglass.com/about/hack-connect-glass-external-monitor-mac-windows/ is the only source I have found. It's a great start, but what if you aren't at home and don't have access to a router control panel?

Comment: As the router is only used to get the IP address, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23559244/how-can-i-get-ip-of-my-glass-when-it-is-connected-by-bluetooth-to-my-mobile) may help.

Comment: have you try splashtop streamer? I mean you should be able to install it on your glass too.